# Airflow DAG cannot import module in root-folder

Tags: airflow

I have the following folder-structure

```
airflow/
     |_dag/
```

as far as I understand, airflow uses the "airflow" folder as root i.e I assume that everything placed in "airflow" would be able to be imported.

Say I have different projects with tasks placed in the following structure

```
airflow/
    |_dag/
    |   |_ mydag.py
    |
    |_myprojects/
           |_projectone/
           |      |_tasks/
           |           |_ mytask.py
           |_projecttwo/
                  |_tasks/
                      |_ mytask.py
```

then I would assume that I in `mydag.py` should be able to import `mytask` from a given project like

```py
#mydag.py
from myprojects.projectone import tasks
```

but I get a `DAG import error;  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myprojects'`.

Is this doable, or should I (somehow) change the airflows PYTHONPATH (and in that case, where is that done?)

Note, I have created `__init__.py` files in the folders.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set the path just before importing `myproject`:

```py
#mydag.py
import sys

# it's important for path being inserted before importing `myproject`
sys.path.insert(0, "..")

from myproject import tasks
```

The second option is to move myproject under the dag folder:

```
airflow
   +-- dag
        +--- myproject
```

The third option is to move some logic into `plugins/` folder.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html

Comment: I'll give it a shot - but how/why does this work? Doesn't airflow use "airflow" as root folder? Btw, I have updated the question since it was not entirely correct what I wrote (I might've simplified it too much at the beginning)

Comment: I just get a `sys.path.insert("..",0); TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: `sys.path` contains the list of search paths for modules. `myproject` is a module, so we simply prepend the path to myproject. `https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.` forgot the order of arguments. 0 must be the first (will update the answer).

Comment: `insert` is the method of `list`

Comment: But, how come airflow cannot see the module when it is in root?

Comment: Airflow uses specific folder structure, which doesn't know about `myproject`, etc. You can find more details in the doc (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html)

Comment: Another option is to move myproject under the dag folder.